# Make Background "Boxes" more responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I must change two things:

1. Move the Header, so that it is on the same "view line" like the
   unordered List.
2. Make a frame around every box, so that any letter
   not hit the frame.

Here is the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt2HE.jpg) and the [url](http://104.40.188.194/) It's on the Startpage before the footer.

**CSS**

https://gist.github.com/DarthKeks/5eacceba397d8d950d06d448f7b473ac

**HTML**

https://gist.github.com/DarthKeks/19a7645e4d831106de674d92f92fa85e

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you know SO provides you with an online editor and viewer for html/css/js?

Comment: Well, first i could not post the code with the editior and second i know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I got what you meant, but maybe trying some `padding` and `margin` might help you:

```
.box {
  padding: 10px;
}
.box h3 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gg3m397b/

Comment: Well you hit the point, it work. But the funny thing is i try it first this way but it didn't work.
So i thank you.